# How to Serve a static JSON file from server?

Tags: json

I need to serve a JSON file to an Android app from a server (VPS webserver).  What is the best way to serve the file?  can I just put it into a directory and retrieve it via app? or is there a service/program that needs to serve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the static JSON file in a public html folder/ www folder. In your Android app, do a httpconnection to get this JSON file.